# How to use Java nio's Files.move in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, nio

I want to use the [`java.nio.file.Files.move()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) method in Matlab.

Although I only need the default behavior, Matlab requires all 3 inputs or would throw the `No method ... with matching signature found.` error. Passing `[]` (which I think gets converted to `null` though not [documented](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-java-methods.html)) gets the `java.lang.NullPointerException` error.

How do I make an `CopyOption` object in Matlab?

---

Example:

```matlab
>> version -java
ans =
    'Java 1.8.0_202-b08 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode

zipFilePath=java.nio.file.Paths.get('test.zip',javaArray('java.lang.String', 0));
zipFileSystem=java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipFilePath,[]);

path1=zipFileSystem.getPath('/test.txt',javaArray('java.lang.String', 0));
path2=zipFileSystem.getPath('/test_changed.txt',javaArray('java.lang.String', 0));

% java.nio.file.Files.move(path1,path2,???); % what should ??? be..

java.nio.file.Files.move(path1,path2,java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES)
No method 'java.nio.file.Files.move' with matching signature found. 

zipFileSystem.close();
```

(I am also attaching my particular use of `.move()` in case there is something else that matters but I don't know.)

Comment: Not used Java calls from Matlab but the third move argument is an array of `CopyOption` . Perhaps try that param as `optArr`  set with `optArr = javaArray('java.nio.file.CopyOption',1)` and assigned contents `optArr(1) = java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES` .

Comment: @DuncG: That solved the problem for me. Would you like to write an answer and we accept answer for the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter to [Files.move](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) is an array of `java.nio.file.CopyOption`, so you'd need to set up an array of `CopyOption` initialised with one entry for the value of the implementing class `java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES`:

```
optArr = javaArray('java.nio.file.CopyOption',1);
optArr(1) = java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES;
java.nio.file.Files.move(path1, path2, optArr);
```